# YouTube python API v3 HttpError 400 subscriptionDuplicate

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube python API v3 to subscribe oauth2 authenticated users to new channels.

```
def add_subscription(youtube, channel_id):
  add_subscription_response = youtube.subscriptions().insert(
    part='id,snippet',
    body=dict(
      snippet=dict(
        resourceId=dict(
          channelId=channel_id
        )
      )
    )).execute()

  return add_subscription_response["id"], add_subscription_response["snippet"]["title"]


youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)

try:
    subscription_id,channel_title = add_subscription(youtube, args.channel_id)
except HttpError, e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
else:
    print "A subscription to '%s' was added." % channel_title
```

From https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert it seems that (or maybe, I understood that...) if the user is already subscribed to the channel described by `channel_id`, the function should raise an `HttpError` with `e.resp.status`=`400` for a `subscriptionDuplicate`.

Nevertheless, if I try to subscribe to a channel the user is already subscribed to, the function normally returns a `subscription_id` and `channel_title`.

Shouldn't it raise `HttpError 400`?

And, if I'm not making mistakes and this is exactly the way the function should work, what could I do to check if the authenticated user is already subscribed to `channel_id` using only `subscriptions().insert()`?

I could call `subscriptions().list()` before, to check if user is subscribed:

```
def is_subscribed(youtube, channel_id):
        is_subscription_response = youtube.subscriptions().list(
                part='id',
                mine='true',
                forChannelId=channel_id
                ).execute()
        if len(is_subscription_response["items"]) == 0:
                return False
        else:
                return True
```

But this would increase quota usage...

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the [`Subscriptions: insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) request and use it in a channel that I already subscribed and I'm not getting the error `subscriptionDuplicate`. I don't know why the API did not return this error.

So to answer your question about how to check if the authenticated user is already subscribed to `channel_id`, use the [`Subscriptions: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) to know all the channel that you subscribed.

Here is the [sample request](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCTEAryTk0JGFSLNZ0tBIw2w&_h=1&), just replace the channelId with your own channelId.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&channelId=YOUR_CHANNEL_ID&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: @KENDdi thanks, yes I know (I just edited today my question to include the function to check subscriptions), but this would increase quota usage. Maybe this is an API bug of `subscriptions().insert()`...

Comment: I will do some testing later, if I found any clue about it I will inform you.

Comment: Are you the one who file this issue "https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8935&q=subscriptionDuplicate&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary" I already vote this issue.